# pdfmake get wrong page position sizes

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I am using it on the client side and my pdf file will contain only images. No matter how many i am adding, first image got opposite width with height. While from second and farther everything looks ok.
[image]
And config that i am using is:

```
var content = [];
for (var j = 0; j < pages.length; j++) {
    if(pages[j].dataUrl) content.push({
        image: pages[j].dataUrl,
        width: 891,
        height: 630
    });
}
var docDefinition = {
    pageSize: {
        width: 891,
        height: 630
    },
    pageOrientation: 'landscape',
    pageMargins: [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    content: content
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange, but with setup

```
pageSize: {
    width: 630,
    height: 891
}
```

It's working. This is lib bug, refer to [Issues of Repo.](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/811)

Comment: try to swap variables